# What is "respond_to" and "do" and "|format|" in this Rails code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  # GET /posts
  # GET /posts.xml
  def index
    @posts = Post.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @posts }
    end
  end
...
```

- What exactly is "respond_to" Is it
  part of rails?
- What is "do" and"|format|"? Why are there vertical separators around format?
- How come Rails knows about the Post model? I didn't import that model. (In Python/Django, you have to import a model before you can use it)

This is from the Ruby on Rails tutorial: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#setting-the-application-home-page

Answer (score 15):

`respond_to` is a rails specific method that defines how requests for different formats (like xml and html) are responded to.  The `do` and `|format|` delineate a ruby block, with `do` acting like a open brace and `end` as a closing brace, and `|format|` defines the block variable that gets its value from the `yield` statement within `responds_to`.

Comment: "do" and "|format|" are standard ruby? (not related to rails?)

Answer (score 3):

the "do" is a RUBY block, and the "|format|" could be anything, its just a variable to use inside that block, here is another example:

```
respond_to do |x|
  x.html # index.html.erb
  x.xml  { render :xml => @posts }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

- [`respond_to` is a Rails method.](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/MimeResponds/respond_to)
- [`do` and the block's parameter (`format`) is standard Ruby.](http://www.robertsosinski.com/2008/12/21/understanding-ruby-blocks-procs-and-lambdas/)
- Rails automatically loads various libraries and exposes them in various locations. Another example are view helpers that are automatically available in templates, but not in controllers. (But [they *can* be](http://www.funonrails.com/2010/12/accessing-helper-modules-in-rails.html), they just aren't by default.)